# Can not install erlang-20.3-1.el7.centos

Tags: erlang

Get following error when install erlang of version 20.3 .
The yum command can be successfully run when the 21 version of erlang hasn't been updated in the repo.
Is this caused by the yum repo updation?

```
#cat erlang_solutions.repo
[erlang-solutions]
name=Centos $releasever - $basearch - Erlang Solutions
baseurl=http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/centos/$releasever/$basearch
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian/erlang_solutions.asc
enabled=1

#yum install erlang-20.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
erlang-solutions | 951 B 00:00:00
erlang-solutions/7/x86_64/primary | 964 kB 00:00:02
erlang-solutions 1038/1038
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package erlang.x86_64 0:20.3-1.el7.centos will be installed
...
--> Processing Dependency: erlang-cosEventDomain(x86-64) = 20.3-1.el7.centos for package: erlang-20.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64
Package erlang-cosEventDomain is obsoleted by erlang, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
...
***Error: Package: erlang-20.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (erlang-solutions)
Requires: erlang-cosEvent(x86-64) = 20.3-1.el7.centos***
...
erlang-cosEvent(x86-64) = 20.2-1.el7.centos
Available: erlang-cosEvent-20.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (erlang-solutions)
erlang-cosEvent(x86-64) = 20.3-1.el7.centos
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had success with my rabbit 3.7.4 install by altering the erlang-solutions.repo file to look like

```
[erlang-solutions]
name=CentOS $releasever - $basearch - Erlang Solutions
baseurl=https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/centos/$releasever/$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/erlang_solutions.asc
enabled=1
exclude=erlang-21*
```